# Usage of Find function with a variable search request

Tags: excel, vba, find

I'm facing a small mystery with the Find function : if get the "researched string" via the code and put it in a varaible, it don't work (gives "Nothing") but if I replace the variable by the actual search request (between some "" of course), it works fine...

Some code will surely help :

The goal here is to :

- get a part code number in one excel file,
- then go to another excel file (containing the prices of all the parts),
- searching for this part number
- and then getting it's price (simple offset) for later usages

I defined MainWrkBk as the main file, where I want to import the data and SecondWkbk as the one where I want to get the part price from

```
Do While Lin < LastRow
    TPICode = Worksheets("C Parts Prices").Range("A" & Lin).Value                                               'Gets the TPI Code (never know...)
    Do While col <= NbCol + 2

        PartNumber = Worksheets("C Parts Prices").Range(Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1) & Lin).Value  'gets the part number stored in the table
        PartNumber = CStr(PartNumber) 'it's useless, but for safety...
        SecondWkbk.Activate 'Go on the second workbook that has just been opened
        Worksheets(PriceListSheet).Range("A1").Select 'this is probably useless

        With Worksheets(PriceListSheet).UsedRange
            Set SearchResult = .Find(What:=PartNumber, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        End With

        If SearchResult Is Nothing Then
            MainWkbk.Activate
        Else
            Worksheets(PriceListSheet).UsedRange.Find(What:=PartNumber, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select
            If SearchResult = PartNumber Then
                PriceEuro = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
                PriceDollars = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)
                MainWkbk.Activate
                Worksheets("C Parts Prices").Range(Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1) & Lin + 2).Value = PriceEuro

            ElseIf SearchResult = "" Then
                MainWkbk.Activate
            End If
        End If


        'Worksheets(TheYear).Select
        'Worksheets(TheYear).Range(Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1) & Lin).Value = PartNumber


        col = col + 1
    Loop
    col = PosStartColumnNb
    Lin = Lin + 3
Loop
```

So, on the line :

```
With Worksheets(PriceListSheet).UsedRange
            Set SearchResult = .Find(What:=PartNumber, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Address                                         
        End With
```

1) If I keep the variable PartNumber, whatever is inside, it give back a "nothing", meaning it don't find the data...

2) On the other hand, if in the code I replace PartNumber by its actual number, something like "BR58JE3SO" it is found immediately...

3)If I replace the line

```
PartNumber = Worksheets("C Parts Prices").Range(Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1) & Lin).Value
```

by a simple `PartNumber = "BR58JE3SO"` , it works fine...

I, of course, tried it that way too :

```
Set SearchResult = Worksheets(PriceListSheet).UsedRange.Find(What:=PartNumber, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
```

No difference :(

May someone explain me what's happening, please?

Edit : a small image to show that :
[image]

Comment: Have you printed out the `PartNumber` to see which value is assigned to it in each iteration? Try adding a `debug.print PartNumber` before the search is executed to check if it's what you expected. The result will show up in your `immediate window`.

Comment: @StavrosJon Hello, I tried this, it gives me the "researched code", as expected... I also check it by running the code step by step and keeping the cursor on the name of the variable, and I added a message box to display it. 
Same goes for "SearchResult" which makes a nice bug when trying to display the "nothing" value... (Run Time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set). Of course, I defined the variables at the beginning of the code as strings (I tried with variant for safety, no difference)

Comment: I don't know if it's something usefull, but when I apply the PartNumber = "BR58JE3SO" and the find function works, it gives me back the content of the cell it found and not it's "range" location...

Comment: I tried it like that :
``` With Worksheets(PriceListSheet).UsedRange
            Set SearchResult = .Find(What:=MainWkbk.Worksheets("C Parts Prices").Range(Split(Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1) & Lin).Value, LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)                                          'Searching for the words 'Reference : ' as the ref is just after it
        End With
```
No change.

Comment: Please get rid of the `.Activate` and '.Select'. Since you have declared `Workbook` variables, you should access the worksheet like so `SecondWkbk.Worksheets(PriceListSheet)`. And I'm guessing the workbook variables have been `set` correctly and `PriceListSheet` has been assigned with the correct string representing the worksheet's name right?

Comment: @StavrosJon I guess you speak about the "MainWkbk.activate" and the "Worksheets(PriceListSheet).Range("A1").Select"? First one is here for safety reasons, i switch several times from one worksheet to the other. The second is kind of useless as the comment says, but that's not my problem...

Comment: I just tried to past the value I search from the MainWkbk to the SecondWkbk (in cell XFD1048576) and did a search by pointing on it... It works -_-
I'm lost on the understanding of this find, and I'd prefer not to touch the second file as it's not my work to do so ^^, Would you/someone have a clean answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently, the only solution would be to create a loop passing through all the cells of the second workbook...
Thank's Find function :'(

Comment: This does not seem like an answer to the question. There is no reason why searching using a variable could give different results than using same constants. There is something else involved that is not shown in the question.

Comment: @BrakNicku It's "searching in another worksheet using a variable"... And I agree, there must be something else, but I showed everything linked to the interesting part of the Find function, I tried every way to past the data, nothing worked :(

Comment: For me (if the description is accurate) there is only one possible explanation: `PartNumber` variable does not contain what you think it does - for example contains some non printable characters. It is easy to check with `Debug.Print PartNumber = "BR58JE3SO"`. Or using simple formula `=rng1=rng2` where ranges point to cells with "BR58JE3SO" in both workbooks. If I am right, then you have to figure, what is the extra character(s) in Partnumber that makes find fail.

Comment: @BrakNicku Well, I would agree with you, and to be sure, I tried kind of "everything possible" (I didn't show it) including writing the line PartNumber = "BR58JE3SO"... This, on the line just before the "Find" function... No difference; it don't find it :'(  For now, I have a loop passing through the file, it's not sexy, but works (well). Thanks for your help anyway :-)

Comment: In fact in the question itself you wrote something opposite: _If I replace the line ... by a simple PartNumber = "BR58JE3SO" , it works fine too..._

Comment: @BrakNicku Yes, if instead of "linking PartNumber to the other excel workbook", I give it a value, it works. If the macro goes in the other workbook to put the value in PartNumber, the "Find" don't work -_- (Remember I try to pass through all the data of another excel workbook I opened before)... Anyway, I went around the problem with a loop passing through all the values... that's not sexy, but working :(